# TensorFlow mnist_softmax tutorial b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])) getting error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_values'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am Getting error below when running the following statement

```
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
```

When I run the code line by line in python in this statement I'm getting error

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
      b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

in append

```
    self._values.append(self._type_checker.CheckValue(value))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_values'
```

Python 3.7 OSX

Here is the complete code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None


def main(_):
  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
  y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

  # The raw formulation of cross-entropy,
  #
  #   tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(y)),
  #                                 reduction_indices=[1]))
  #
  # can be numerically unstable.
  #
  # So here we use tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on the raw
  # outputs of 'y', and then average across the batch.
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  # Train
  for _ in range(1000):`enter code here`
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                      y_: mnist.test.labels}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Complete error log when I run the whole file

```
/Users/av/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.7
  return f(*args, **kwds)
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist.py", line 79, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Users/av/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "mnist.py", line 41, in main
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
  File "/Users/av/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1439, in zeros
    output = constant(zero, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/av/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Users/av/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 483, in make_tensor_proto
    append_fn(tensor_proto, proto_values)
SystemError: <built-in function AppendFloat32ArrayToTensorProto> returned NULL without setting an error
```

What should be done to solve this problem?

Comment: post the code where you initialize the variable, perform operations, run and line where error appears

Comment: added the complete code @asakryukin

Comment: please add error log as well

Comment: added error log too @asakryukin